# Is it safe to delete empty function in parent class?

Tags: php, oop, zend-framework, extends, function-declaration

I have public function beforeDelete() in almost every class of CMS. Unfortunately some clever people before me created some of them with `($rowId)` param and some of them with no parameters at all.

Parent `Main_Admin_Module` has empty function declaration like this:

```
public function beforeDelete() {}
```

but because of this, I'm getting **errors** like

> ERR: Declaration of Model_EshopCategories::beforeDelete() should be
>   compatible with that of Admin_Module_Main::beforeDelete()

because (obviously) declaration with `($rowId)` is not compatible with `(empty)` one.

Unfortunately this prevents Json responses since response body contains error and is therefore damaged, so I want to fix this one.

My question is: Can I simply get rid of parent method or should I rewrite every single childs beforeDelete to fix this? I tried to do `($rowId = null)` in parent method and it didn't work.

Comment: what is the visibility given to these function in parent vs child `public/protected/private` ?

Comment: You should rewrite all the methods and make sure they are all consistent. You could use an interface to enforce the method signature is consistent.

Comment: @jitendrapurohit public, they are both (all models and parent model) public

Comment: @GerardRoche well that's unfortunate, but why it won't let me bypass it by making variable with default value in Main_Module? with `public function beforeDelete($rowId = null) {}`

Comment: It won't let you bypass it because it's not compatible with the declaration in `Admin_Module_Main::beforeDelete()`. Meaning your method signature must be the same as the one in `Admin_Module_Main::beforeDelete()`.

Comment: @GerardRoche No, I meant changing this declaration itself. But now I'm thinking that I might be wrong because it works for calling method not its declaration, right?

Comment: it should actually be allowing you to add an optional argument in the signature: "if the child class defines an optional argument, where the abstract method's signature does not, there is no conflict in the signature." -- http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.abstract.php

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122294/discussion-between-gerard-roche-and-vladimir-litovkin).

Answer (score 0):

It appears to me that the base method is an unnecessary burden, since it doesn't do anything and enforces rules that cannot be followed by all subclasses. Especially if it's called with different parameters under different circumstances, this method shouldn't be a part of the common API of `Admin_Module_Main` class.

My suggestion would be to delete the `beforeDelete()` method from `Admin_Module_Main`.

The alternative that doesn't require you to delete the base method would be to go through every subclass of `Admin_Module_Main` and make the parameters optional (plus the code that handles the default value in the optional parameter). This might be a better solution in case you don't know everything about the callers of `beforeDelete()` method.

Comment: There may be valid reasons that method exists. For example, some other part of the system may expect that method to exist. Removing it would then mean every class that extends it needs to create that method. And you won't know until runtime if all classes that extend that class has defined the method.

Comment: If there is another part of the system that expects `beforeDelete()` to exist and accept 0 parameters, the program will fail if there is an override that expects more than 0 parameters - and there are such cases here. I stand by my statement that this method cannot be a part of `Admin_Module_Main` if different numbers of parameters are to be expected.

Comment: Child methods can have additional optional arguments. See example 2 http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.abstract.php

Comment: That's another possibility. Added to my answer.

Answer (score -2):

One of the solution to avoid this error if you don't want to fix code in all classes is to change the error_reporting level. Go to your php.ini configuration and update error_reporting in a way like.

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_STRICT
```

or do in the code

```
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_STRICT);
```

E_STRICT level is a reason why you see this error message.

Comment: That only hides the issue.

Comment: I have it enabled by default, but then again if I've made error myself I need to trun it on which, again causes problem with ajax and json

Comment: You should read my explanation carefully. It's not only hide the issue it allows to use this kind of code. If you have hundreds of legacy controllers I wish you good lick to fix all of them in one iteration. @GerardRoche

Comment: @AndrejLudinovskov I think I'll agree with Gerard Roche on this one. I'm forced to use it that way currently and I haven't see any place in any project where something like this actually benefit developer rather then confuse and make debugging and especially optimization harder

Comment: @VladimirLitovkin It's up to you. If you have time to refactor do it.

Comment: Hiding the errors is fine as a temporary measure while refactoring and updating legacy code. It can help reduce the noise of issues and allows you to focus on bigger ticket items. It would cause serious problems if someone was to use it as a design feature.